# Combining combined reducers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, reducers

```
export reducers = combineReducers ({
   app: ...,
   user: ...,
   display:...,
})
```

// in a config file

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
   form: formReducer,
   apollo: apolloReducer,
   reducers
})
```

This leads to a state tree that looks like this,

```
{
  form: {...},
  apollo: {...},
  reducers: {
    app: {...},
    user: {...},
    display: {...}
  }
}
```

I want this...

```
{
  form: {...},
  apollo: {...},
  app: {...},
  user: {...},
  display: {...}
}
```

I tried to ...reducers but tha didn’t work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can have an object with all your reducers,

```
export reducers = {
   app: ...,
   user: ...,
   display:...,
}
```

and then you can

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers ({
   form: formReducer,
   apollo: apolloReducer,
   ...reducers
})
```

Comment: I expect this object approach will work. In any case I thought combinedReducers was capable of resolving this.

Comment: What `combineReducers` returns is just a function, a normal reducer. You cannot use the spread operator on it. What you could do is to "reduce" the "reducers", a.k.a have a reducer that run both `reducers` and `rootReducer`. Example: https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers